# Stored Proc vanished from list, but executes just fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's a strange thing that just happened. 
I had three Stored Procedures but I can only see one now. The vanished procs executes just fine but strangely I can't find them any where.

I do not know how it doesn't exist but executes.

Things I have tried -

```
sp_helptext sp_myproc
```

> Msg 15009, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 54 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] The object 'sp_myproc' does not exist in database 'test'
>   or is invalid for this operation.

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'sp_myproc'))
```

> NULL

```
SELECT object_definition(object_id) as [Proc Definition]
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type='P'
```

> Displays only one proc

```
EXEC sp_myproc
```

> returns data normally

I have also tried Refreshing cache for IntelliSense (CTRL+SHIFT+R)
They are also not available in system procedures

My tree view [image]

Not sure where'd they go. Looking for a way to approach this problem.

Comment: Do You have permissions to view that stored procedure? Are You database owner?

Comment: And do You execute it on test database for sure? Try USE [test] EXEC sp_myproc

Comment: Don't prefix them with `sp_`. There is no need in any "technical" prefix actually. But this one prefix is specifically the bad one. SP does not become table or trigger if has no prefix.

Comment: The db is on my box. I am the owner. `EXEC sp_myproc` works just fine with or without `USE [test]`

Comment: `SELECT object_schema_name(object_id), object_name(object_id)
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type='P'` what is the output?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I see `dbo sp_myproc` in the output

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic953002-149-1.aspx, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/sp-helptext-error

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thanks Ivan, the fault was that the proc was created in master db. strange

Comment: reference text from link below: *The sp_ prefix does not mean what you think it does: most people think sp stands for "stored procedure" when in fact it means "special." Stored procedures (as well as tables and views) stored in master with an sp_ prefix are accessible from any database without a proper reference (assuming a local version does not exist).*
For more info refer [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)